# Prove that $S$ has at most $n$ free points

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

Problem Statement:

Given $m = 2n$, let $S$ be a set of $m$ points on a circle with no two diametrically opposite. Say that $x \in S$ is free if fewer than $n$ points on $S - x$ lie in the semicircle clockwise from $x$. Prove that $S$ has at most $n$ free points.

I was wondering how this can be proven with the pigeonhole principle

Comment: By "two diametrically opposite", do you mean that the $m$ points comes in pairs of 2 diamatrically opposite points, meaning we have the endpoints of $n$ diameters? If yes, then this follows directly from PP.

Comment: Ah there's a typo in my post. It's supposed to be no two diametrically opposite. Sorry.

Comment: It can be proven directly since for every free point, there is a non free point.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Show that 2 diametrically opposite points cannot both be free points.

Hence, the result follows from PP.